# Can one access online the subtitles for the UT-tagged videos in Bayerisches Fernsehen’s Mediathek?

Tags: resource, learning, listening-comprehension

I have found that watching German media videos with subtitles has helped my aural comprehension (I am not a native speaker of German). Therefore, I am particularly interested in locating subtitled German media videos available for free online.

Bayerisches Fernsehen (BR) offers many videos of previously-aired programs through its [*Mediathek*](http://www.br.de/mediathek/index.html) site.

Some of these videos have the tag **UT**, meaning that subtitles (*Untertitel*) are available for them.

Here’s an example of one such **UT**-tagged video: http://www.br.de/mediathek/video/sendungen/nachrichten/sendung-vom-26122015_x-100.html

(I reached the video above through [this page](http://www.br.de/mediathek/video/programm/index.html), where it is clearly marked **UT** [it's the entry titled "Rundschau 16.45 Uhr"]:

[image]

this page, however, is ephemeral, so chances are that it won't look the same in a few hours.)

When I watch such **UT**-tagged videos online (either using a desktop computer or a tablet), I see *no* subtitles at all<sup>1</sup>, nor any way to enable such subtitles through the player’s interface.

Is there some other way to access the subtitles for the **UT**-tagged shows in BR’s *Mediathek*?

---

BTW, although I’ve focused on BR’s *Mediathek*, I have found similar situations in most German media’s *Mediathek* websites (WDR’s, NDR’s, etc., with the sole exception of ARD’s). Basically, all these *Mediathek* sites have videos tagged with **UT**, but I can’t get any subtitles when I watch any of them. I'm hoping that the answer that works for BR’s *Mediathek* videos may also work for the rest.

As I noted, ARD’s *Mediathek* is the only exception I know of; its **UT**-tagged videos reliably include a **UT**-toggle in their players, and the subtitles do appear on screen when enabled, as one would expect.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The only subtitle-related indication I have found for the BR videos is the label [**UT** Seite 150] that is shown briefly on the screen towards the beginning of the playback.  I understand (from the comments below) that this refers to a [Teletext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext) page, and is therefore not applicable to the videos available through BR's Mediathek.</sup>

Comment: _Seite 150_ is referring to [Teletext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext) page 150 during regular broadcast.

Comment: For http://www.br.de/mediathek/video/sendungen/berggeschichten/reinhold-messner-und-zaha-hadid-bauen-ein-museum-102.html I can turn on subtitles as long as I do not choose full screen (on an iPad).

Comment: Please clean up your question to leave only those parts that will be relevant to future visitors. As it stands now the question you had was an issue arising from **a bug of an external website** which is entirely unrelated to the German language.

Comment: @Takkat: I agree entirely that in the end this question turned out to be entirely unrelated to the German language; IMO the right solution is to delete the question altogether.  It is also, by far, the simplest one.  I am all for this course of action.

Comment: +1 for learning German with the Bavarian television, though. It makes me proud =3

Comment: @kjo: we have a nice answer, and this question may be interesting for future visitors, so IMO an edit would be the appropriate action rather than deleting it.

Comment: @Takkat: at least lest be consistent; many things could be of interest to future visitors (stock quotes, sports trivia, you-name-it), but we disallow them for being off-topic.  I think the same should go for this one...

Comment: @kjo: entirely up to you... [edit] your question to get rid of the bug report,  make it of more general interest, and take care the existing answer still is valid. Then we all will be happy to reopen it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video you linked to does not have subtitles (and isn’t marked as such, either, at least nowhere that I looked). For videos that have subtitles, there is a “UT” button in the player that may be used to toggle subtitles. An example of this can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot of “Die NSA und ich” with subtitles shown]

„Seite 150“ refers to [Teletext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext) page 150 during regular broadcast. It is not applicable to Internet videos in the *Mediathek*.

Comment: I reached the video I linked through this page: http://www.br.de/mediathek/video/programm/index.html; it is clearly marked **UT** in that page.  It looks like now my problem reduces to finding a reliable why to locate such videos.  The example of the page I linked shows at least one way that is completely unreliable.

Comment: @kjo: Here is [what I see on that page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ss2XS.png) – no _UT_.

Comment: That's amazing.  I just added my own screenshot to my post, showing exactly the opposite to what yours shows.

Comment: @Takkat: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Are you saying that the screenshot I posted is somehow fraudulent???

Comment: @kjo: no idea, may have been a bug to the website or whateverer but on my browser here there is no UT tag: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4IcOo.png

Comment: @Takkat: OK, I now understand what's going on.  First: apparently, the page I listed marks with UT *also* those shows for which subtitles are available while the show is streaming live, even though this information is (possibly) irrelevant to videos archived in the Mediathek.  (Note that in my screenshot, but not in yours nor chirlu's, the show I referred not only had the **UT** tag, but also a **LIVESTREAM** tag.)  Second, and even more screwed up, is the fact that the website uses the user's *local time* to decide what entries to mark as **LIVESTREAM**.  This means that...

Comment: @Takkat: ...people in different time zones will see different tags on the same item in that page.  Indeed, eventually I saw both **LIVESTREAM** and **UT** markers disappear from the listing for the video I originally posted as an example.